# How to simulate vacuum clamping?

Tags: gazebo-all-versions

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want simulate a robot with vacuum cups. The robot moves the cups to touch a light part. When the cups touch the part, vacuum is activated and the part is clamp by the cups.

While vacuum is activated, the part follow the movement of the vacuun cups.

Could it be simulated with a pluging ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6306/how-to-simulate-vacuum-clamping-?/) by [jalfonso](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/776/jalfonso/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-05-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

you could check for contacts between the cups and the object, when contact is detected you can dynamically create a fixed joint between the two links to simulate the vacuum, thus the object will follow the movement of the vacuum cup.

If the idea suits you, check out the `gazebo/physics/Gripper.cc` example where fix joints are created. For detecting the contact use a contact sensor, [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=contact_sensor) is a tutorial.

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2014-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mehdi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1195/mehdi/) on 2015-06-11**:
Is there any ROS interface for dynamically spawning such a joint?

**Comment by [Abdullah](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2617/abdullah/) on 2016-08-29**:
Thank you so much for the answer, I was just thinking the same thing for the same problem. Yet when I see Gripper class I would have to use the following code right?

**Comment by [Abdullah](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2617/abdullah/) on 2016-08-29**:


<grasp_check>
<attach_steps>5</attach_steps>
<detach_steps>10</detach_steps>
<min_contact_count>2</min_contact_count>
</grasp_check>
<gripper_link>gripper_active_finger_link</gripper_link>
<palm_link>gripper_static_finger_link</palm_link>

**Comment by [Abdullah](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2617/abdullah/) on 2016-08-29**:
So what if we do not use any other link but only one link palm link , would it work?